# Why is the output of these two codes "cutting out"

Tags: roblox

There is something wrong with the output of two pieces of code. I am stumped with what could have happened.

EDIT: I found out that the function was firing 14 times when it should have only fired 10 times.

(Running inside a script)

```
SpeechEvent = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("SpeechEvent")
SpeechEventFinished = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("SpeechEventFinished")
AnimationEvent = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("AnimationEvent")
game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("ChapterStart").OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    print("test")
    wait(1)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("Hello everyone", "Dictator", 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    wait(1)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients(", dictator speaking.", nil, 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    wait(3)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients(nil, nil, nil, true, nil)
    wait(0.1)
    AnimationEvent:FireAllClients(1)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("I am here to congratulate you for your victory in the war", "Dictator", 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    wait(3)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients(nil, nil, nil, true, nil)
    wait(0.1)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("It was a ", "Dictator", 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("gruesome ", nil, 0.5, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("war, one filled with ", nil, 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("blood and sorrow, ", nil, 0.5, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("but you continued with consistency and determination.", nil, 0.05, false, nil)
    wait(3)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients(nil, nil, nil, true, nil)
    wait(0.1)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("That is the mindset of a true warrior of Apzazch.", "Dictator", 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    wait(1)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients(" Well done.", nil, 0.05, false, nil)
    SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
    wait(3)
    SpeechEvent:FireAllClients(nil, nil, nil, true, nil)
end)
```

(running inside a localscript)

```
function onFire(text, character, delaychar, textwipe, returndata)
    if character ~= nil then
        textFinal = character .. ": " .. text
    else
        textFinal = text
    end
    if textwipe == false then
        for count = 0, string.len(textFinal), 1 do
            print(string.sub(textFinal, count, count) .. "         " .. count)
            script.Parent.Parent.SpeechBox.Enabled = true
            script.Parent.Parent.SpeechBox.SpeechBox.Text = script.Parent.Parent.SpeechBox.SpeechBox.Text .. string.sub(textFinal, count, count)
            wait(delay)
        end
        game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("SpeechEventFinished"):FireServer(returndata)
    else
        script.Parent.Parent.SpeechBox.SpeechBox.Text = ""
        script.Parent.Parent.SpeechBox.Enabled = false
    end
end

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("SpeechEvent").onClientEvent:connect(onFire)
```

This is what the Gui says:
Dictator: Hello Everyone, dictator speaking
Dictator: I am here to congratulate you for your victory in the war
Dictator: It was a gruesome war, one filled with blood and sorrow, but you continued with consistency and determination. 
Dictator: That is the miWell done

Its even weirder when you look at the output

```
  test
           0
  D         1
  i         2
  c         3
  t         4
  a         5
  t         6
  o         7
  r         8
  :         9
            10
  H         11
  e         12
  l         13
  l         14
  o         15
            16
  e         17
  v         18
  e         19
  r         20
  y         21
  o         22
  n         23
  e         24
           0
  ,         1
            2
  d         3
  i         4
  c         5
  t         6
  a         7
  t         8
  o         9
  r         10
            11
  s         12
  p         13
  e         14
  a         15
  k         16
  i         17
  n         18
  g         19
  .         20
           0
  D         1
  i         2
  c         3
  t         4
  a         5
  t         6
  o         7
  r         8
  :         9
            10
  I         11
            12
  a         13
  m         14
            15
  h         16
  e         17
  r         18
  e         19
            20
  t         21
  o         22
            23
  c         24
  o         25
  n         26
  g         27
  r         28
  a         29
  t         30
  u         31
  l         32
  a         33
  t         34
  e         35
            36
  y         37
  o         38
  u         39
            40
  f         41
  o         42
  r         43
            44
  y         45
  o         46
  u         47
  r         48
            49
  v         50
  i         51
  c         52
  t         53
  o         54
  r         55
  y         56
            57
  i         58
  n         59
            60
  t         61
  h         62
  e         63
            64
  w         65
  a         66
  r         67
           0
  D         1
  i         2
  c         3
  t         4
  a         5
  t         6
  o         7
  r         8
  :         9
            10
  I         11
  t         12
            13
  w         14
  a         15
  s         16
            17
  a         18
            19
           0
  g         1
  r         2
  u         3
  e         4
  s         5
  o         6
  m         7
  e         8
            9
           0
  w         1
  a         2
  r         3
  ,         4
            5
  o         6
  n         7
  e         8
            9
  f         10
  i         11
  l         12
  l         13
  e         14
  d         15
            16
  w         17
  i         18
  t         19
  h         20
            21
           0
  b         1
  l         2
  o         3
  o         4
  d         5
            6
  a         7
  n         8
  d         9
            10
  s         11
  o         12
  r         13
  r         14
  o         15
  w         16
  ,         17
            18
           0
  b         1
  u         2
  t         3
            4
  y         5
  o         6
  u         7
            8
  c         9
  o         10
  n         11
  t         12
  i         13
  n         14
  u         15
  e         16
  d         17
            18
  w         19
  i         20
  t         21
  h         22
            23
  c         24
  o         25
  n         26
  s         27
  i         28
  s         29
  t         30
  e         31
  n         32
  c         33
  y         34
            35
  a         36
  n         37
  d         38
            39
  d         40
  e         41
  t         42
  e         43
  r         44
  m         45
  i         46
  n         47
  a         48
  t         49
  i         50
  o         51
  n         52
  .         53
           0
  D         1
  i         2
  c         3
  t         4
  a         5
  t         6
  o         7
  r         8
  :         9
            10
  T         11
  h         12
  a         13
  t         14
            15
  i         16
  s         17
            18
  t         19
  h         20
  e         21
            22
  m         23
  i         24
           0
           25
            1
           26
  W         2
           27
  e         3
           28
  l         4
           29
  l         5
           30
            6
           31
  d         7
           32
  o         8
           33
  n         9
           34
  e         10
           35
  .         11
           36
           37
           38
           39
           40
           41
           42
           43
           44
           45
           46
           47
           48
           49
           50
           51
           52
           53
           54
           55
           56
           57
           58
           59
```

So any way I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you are sending

```
SpeechEvent:FireAllClients("but you continued with consistency and determination.", nil, 0.05, false, nil)
```

you are not waiting for your finished event. In the next line you should put

```
SpeechEventFinished.onServerEvent:Wait()
```

Even though you are waiting for 3 seconds, the next time you are sending text, the following Wait() function will catch that event and go right on to the next speech line, which will interfere with the line that is still in the middle of playing/displaying.